# Error in joomla module- vertical-scroll-recent-article-joomla-module with the latest version joomla3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

i am getting start with joomla 3 and completely new to joomla

Set up joomla in localhost . i tried to install  vertical-scroll-recent-article-joomla-module with the latest version

i got 3 error[image]

1 and 2nd error gone when change the function getArticleList and loadScripts change to static function. Do we really need to change inside a module readily available?

i dont have any idea how to solve the 3rd

**ERROR  Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\joomla\modules\mod_vertical_scroll_recent_article\helper.php on line 24**

```
public static function loadScripts(&$params)
    {
    line 24:    $doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addScript(JURI::Root(true).'/modules/mod_vertical_scroll_recent_article/mod_vertical_scroll_recent_article.js');
    }
```

i tried removing '&' the error gone ,but the view is not rendering in the front end

Comment: are you sure that module is compatible with Joomla3.0

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/latest-news/14320 i dowloaded from the following link. it is showing compatible with joomla 2 and joomla 3x. how to check otherwise

Comment: check my answer its works for me, the module is written for lower version or the developers forgot to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public static function loadScripts(&$params)
    {
       $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); //On line 24 remove the & 
       $doc->addScript(JURI::Root(true).'/modules/mod_vertical_scroll_recent_article/mod_vertical_scroll_recent_article.js');
    }
```

This module is written for Joomla lower versions that why this kind of errors.

Hope its works..

Comment: i also did the same and it work well for a fresh installation as i explained  . i have the same module in an existing project and it is not rendering the view when i removed & it is in joomla 3.1

Comment: with & the error in that existing project ? while using this modul

Comment: same error occurred will install with the latest link with joomla 3.1 of the module. when making the function as static and removing the &  all errors gone. but view is not rendering

Comment: can u suggest any other module equivalent to this with joomla 3 support

Comment: &JFactory::getDocument(); seems to be deprecated function is there any equivalent for this

Comment: Normally it works that much we need to do for making its compatible with Joomla 3.x are you sure its not displaying anything it may due to you have no latest articles.

Comment: No JFactory::getDocument(); its not depreciated the usage of & is restricted in Joomla2.5 and above